# Review audits ignore filters

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits

I was reviewing and set the filter to questions only.  I then received an answer to review, which turned out to be an audit.  Audits seem to bypass filters, so if you receive something that your filter would normally block, that is a clear indication that it is an audit.

Comment: There are many indications that an audit is in fact an audit. Seasoned reviewers can smell them ;)

Comment: @Scratte Such as?

Comment: @Nick This question is about the bug.  The fact that it reveals an audit is only a consequence.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery No, that is only about tags, whereas this is about all filters.

Comment: @Anonymous Doesn't matter, it's still the same thing - audits don't respect filters, and that's by design.

Comment: Indications are inconsistencies. For example it says there are 3 other Answers, but none are presented. The old review system could say: "Answers: 0" and then "Accepted: Yes" :D

Comment: *"if you receive something that your filter would normally block, that is a clear indication that it is an audit"* - great! Means you're paying attention! That's the whole point of the audit. To make sure you're not just randomly clicking away...

Answer (score 7):

Even if this *is* a bug (and I'm not sure that it is), then it isn't a *problematical* bug.

Why? Because audits are designed, first and foremost, to make sure you are paying attention. If you have sufficient wit to notice that you are being asked to review an *answer*, when you explicitly asked to review only *questions*, then you have demonstrated that you are, indeed, paying attention (and *not* "robo-reviewing").

Possibly useful/relevant: [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/616624)